# PowerShell script that runs on a server checks TCP connection and then outputs it to CSV

Tags: powershell, networking, system-administration

I'm pretty new to PowerShell so I've not quite got it down and this has been a learning experience as well as possibly something I can refine to be practical in the future, but I'm trying to launch this script via SCCM to a couple hundred servers and have it write the results to share drive in a CSV.

Before I get started let me say nmap and most third-party tools are out of the question.

The purpose of the script is to see if it can connect on a designated port that our DCs are listening on. I want the output to list the hostname of the server initiating the connection, the particular DC it's attempting to connect on, and whether it succeeded or failed. Running it on one server would look something like this:

```
ComputerName    TcpTestSucceeded    Hostname
DC1                 TRUE             Host1
DC2                 FALSE            Host1
DC3                 True             Host1
```

I want to get my output right before I tackle the external writing issue and right now it's kind of funky because I tried to do some object manipulation.

What I have so far:

```
$hostname=$env:computername

$DC01='DC1'
$DC02='DC2'

$Result=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList 
$Result|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Hostname -Value $hostname

$dcArray=$DC01,$DC02

ForEach ($dc in $dcArray){
    $Result+=Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $dc -Port 54001
    $computerName= $Result|Select -Property ComputerName
    $tcpTestSucceeded=$Result|Select -Property TcpTestSucceeded


}
$resultObject=New-Object psObject -Property@{'Hostname'=$hostname;'ComputerName'=$computerName;'TcpTestSucceeded'=$tcpTestSucceeded}

$resultObject|Write-Output
```

Currently what I get is a hashtable in a table:

```
ComputerName                         TcpTestSucceeded             Hostname      
------------                         ----------------              --------      
{@{ComputerName=DC01}, @{ComputerName=DC02}} {@{TcpTestSucceeded=False}, @{TcpTestSucceeded=False}} Host1
```

In case anyone is confused 'ComputerName' is supposed to be the name of the DC receiving the connection and 'Hostname' is the server attempting it.

Comment: Move `$resultObject = New-Object ...` up one line (so it's inside the `ForEach(){}` loop body)

Comment: That's where I had it originally, and I get the exact same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding members to your new object that are in themselves objects.

To remedy this, you need to use the -expandProperty switch on your select statements.

You are also having problems with scope because you placed $resultObject outside yout ForEach loop. which is why you only have 1 item in your output.
You are also adding Properties to an arraylist not to the items in that arraylist.

But in short, you are complicating several things unnecessarially
As you already have an object with most of the properties you need, you can just select properties from it.

Try this:

```
$hostname=$env:computername

$DC01='DC1'
$DC02='DC2'
$dcArray=$DC01,$DC02

$Result=@()    
ForEach ($dc in $dcArray){
    $Result+=Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $dc -Port 54001

}

$result | select @{Name="Hostname";Expression={$Hostname}}, ComputerName, PingSucceeded
```

If you want to be more verbose / specific with the output members you can do something like:

```
$hostname=$env:computername

$DC01='DC1'
$DC02='DC2'
$dcArray=$DC01,$DC02

ForEach ($dc in $dcArray){
    $Result=Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $dc -Port 54001
    $Out = new-object PSObject -Property @{Hostname=$hostname;ComputerName=$($Result.computerName);TcpTestSucceeded=$($Result.PingSucceeded)}
    $out
}
```

Comment: I get unexpected Token errors in the first solution in the select statement and 'Assignment expression is not valid. The input assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a variable or a property.' in the second one.

Comment: Sorry I didn't run it through the sanity filter, then I only fixed one of the 2 options.. I have made edits, they should work now.    P.S. Welcome to PowerShell!

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew it had something to do with my object manipulation I'm still trying to wrap my head around it. I originally had something pretty similar to your second solution, but ditched because I didn't know the syntax.